# Undefined method when trying to create a new database record in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to save a new record as seen below. However I keep getting an error saying that `response_output=` is an undefined method. In my FormResponse table I have a column called response_output... so I'm not really understanding why this is failing to save the record.

Controller

```
class Form::SubmitsController < ApplicationController
  def submit_forms
    @response = 'some xml output'

    new_response = Form::FormResponse.new
    new_response.response_output = @response
    new_response.save
  end
end
```

Comment: 1) Did you run `rake db:migrate`? 2) Check model columns use `Form::FormResponse.attribute_names` command in Rails console.

Comment: So I guess this might be part of the issue... I created the migration in the main Application db>migrate folder. But I'm using engines and moved the migration to the engines migrate folder. I ran `rake db:migrate` again but nothing happened. When I look at my database the columns are there. But when I check the attributes all that's returned is `["id"]`

Comment: Try to restart server and Rails console and check columns again. Rails doesn't reload engines automatically.

Comment: Ok, turns out it was something unrelated to the migration... My `self.table_name` in the model was not pluralized.... Damn (Palm to face)... thanks for your help though @maxd